# Не работает cuda toolkit и cmake

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, cmake, pytorch, cuda

Устанавил cuda toolkit и запустил файл для работы с pytorch c++ и возникает ошибка:
CMake Error at C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.28/Modules/CMakeDetermineCompilerId.cmake:780 (message):Compiling the CUDA compiler identification source file
"CMakeCUDACompilerId.cu" failed.

Compiler:

Build flags: -D_WINDOWS;-Xcompiler=/W3 /GR /EHsc

Id flags: --keep;--keep-dir;tmp -v
что делать???

Comment: смотреть логи сборки.